# Excel array formula to MySQL equivalent

Tags: mysql, excel, excel-formula

I've been using a pretty simple array formula in excel to crunch some datasets but they're getting too large and absolutely destroying my computers performance whenever I update the calculations.

The excel sheet and MySQL database are laid out like so:

```
+-Timestamp-+-value-+
| 1340816430|  .02  |
---------------------
```

x600,000 rows

Here's the excel formula:

```
{=AVERAGEIFS(B:B,A:A,"<"&A1+1000,A:A,">"&A1-1000)}
```

That returns the average of the values, and is the third column in the excel sheet. Is there any plausible way for me to create a MySQL query that performs a similar operation and returns a column with the values that would have been in the third column had I run excel's formula?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not extremely good at remembering excel's formulas: but is that formula generating an average between cell A and B on a per-row basis or collectively?

Comment: @Battle_707 the formula is averaging the values in column B that have a timestamp of +/- 1000 (column A), on a per-row basis. Each row would have its own value of the points that are within range on either side of it.

Comment: I am sorry, but I still don't quite understand. How can you do a per-row average if the only number you use to average is row B? If I'm guessing what you want to do is to select all rows that have a value of +/- 1000 from a certain timestamp and average between those. In MySQL that would be done through the use over the AVG function and some conditional selects. For example: `SELECT AGV(B) FROM t1 WHERE a > '$t-1000' AND a < '$t+1000'` where $t is the timestamp. If you index this table (t1) properly, this query should be really fast.

Comment: Do I understand the formula and your explanation correctly: for each cell in column B you would find other cells from B which have a timestamp in the range of +/-1000 and show the average of those in column C? If that's the case, I think it's difficult to make an equivalent MySQL query - it's essentially a loop-based operation, not a set-based operation (which RMBSes are designed for).

Comment: @Battle_707 Sorry, I'm having a hard time synthesizing the concept. Yours would work on one timestamp, however what I'm trying to get out of it is an individual value for each row. What I mean is that each average value is a value that is the average of all rows with the timestamp +/- 1000 of the timestamp of that row.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think that will be possible just inside MySQL, and doing it through an external loop would be highly inefficient. May I ask why it is you are trying to do this in the first place?

Comment: @Battle_707 have a look see at the answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are happy using Excel formulas you can speed up this calculation a lot (factor of over 3000 on my system). Assuming that Column A contains the timestamps in ASCENDING ORDER and Column B the values (if not already sorted then use Excel Sort). 
in Column C put =IFERROR(MATCH(A1-1000,$A:$A,1),1) and copy down. This calculates the row number of the row 1000 timestamp less. 
in Column D put =IFERROR(MATCH(A1+1000,$A:$A,1),1048576) and copy down. This calculates the row number of the row 1000 timestamp more.
in column E put =AVERAGE(OFFSET(B1,C1-ROW(),0,D1-C1+1,1)) and copy down. This calculates the average of the subset range from the first row to the last row.
 On my system this full calculates 1000K rows in 20 seconds.
 The disadvantage of this method is that its volatile so will recalculate whenever you make a change, but I assume that you are in Manual calculation mode anyway.

Comment: Nice optimization! I think other interested readers would benefit from the write up you blogged as well (^:

Comment: OK - for those interested in a more detailed explanation see http://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2012/07/09/makeing-the-most-of-your-xips-part2-when-40-mxips-for-averageifs-is-too-slow/

Comment: You should share the [shortlink](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11385680/88173) if you want the [Announcer](http://stackoverflow.com/badges/260/announcer) badge.

Comment: This has been the most helpful, succinct and flawless answer I have ever received on SO, @CharlesWilliams.

Answer (score 2):

MySQL code:

```
select
  a.timestamp t1,
  avg(x.value) average_value
from
  mydata a inner join (
    select 
      timestamp, 
      value
    from mydata
    ) x
    on x.timestamp between a.timestamp - 1000 and a.timestamp + 1000
group by 
  a.timestamp
order by
  t1
;
```

I would like to think that without the Excel overhead this will perform far better, but I can't promise it will be lightning fast on 600k rows. You will definitely want to index `Timestamp`. See also [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/62026/1/0) I created.

Comment: Thanks Andy. I'll have a look when I get back to a computer. Looks promising.

Comment: I appreciate the vote of confidence, but out of honesty I have to say I tried this today with variously large numbers of rows and sadly, MySQL chokes somewhere north of 10k rows on my PC despite indexing. At this point I would recommend @CharlesWilliams solution.

Comment: Unfortunately I ran into the same issue. I didn't dig any deeper, but I let it run overnight on a m2.4xlarge RDS volume and it didn't finish. Oh well.

Answer (score 0):

@Peter You can stick with Excel if you want to. Just use http://xllarray.codeplex.com. The formula you want is `=AVERAGE(ARRAY.MASK((A:A>A1 + 1000)*(A:A<A1 - 1000), B:B)`. 1MM rows on my junky laptop calculate in under 1 second. Be sure to Ctrl-Shift-Enter it as an array formula.

If you don't want to build the code, you can grab the add-in and help file off my SkyDrive: http://sdrv.ms/JtaMIV

Comment: If your junky laptop calculates 1 million copies of your formula in 1 second then I want one!

Answer (score 0):

@Charles. Ah, no. It is only for one formula. Misread the spec.

If you wanted to push the calculation into C++ and expose it as an xll, here is how you might do that:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>
#include "xll/xll.h"

using namespace xll;

typedef traits<XLOPER12>::xword xword;

static AddIn12 xai_windowed_average(
    L"?xll_windowed_average", XLL_FP12 XLL_FP12 XLL_FP12 XLL_DOUBLE12,
    L"WINDOWED.AVERAGE", L"Time, Value, Window"
);
_FP12* WINAPI
xll_windowed_average(_FP12* pt, _FP12* pv, double dt)
{
#pragma XLLEXPORT
static xll::FP12 a(size(*pt), 1);

double* bt0 = &pt->array[0];
double* bv0 = &pv->array[0];
double* bt = std::lower_bound(begin(*pt), end(*pt), *bt0 - dt);
double* et = std::lower_bound(begin(*pt), end(*pt), *bt0 + dt);

for (xword i = 0; i < size(*pt); ++i) {
    a[i] = (bt == et) ? 0 : std::accumulate(bv0 + (bt - bt0), bv0 + (et - bt0), 0)/(et - bt); 

    // update the window
    bt = std::lower_bound(bt, end(*pt), pt->array[i] - dt);
    et = std::lower_bound(bt, end(*pt), pt->array[i] + dt);
}

return a.get();
}
```